# Python - Merge list of dictionary with same values

Tags: python, list, dictionary

- I have a list of dictionary as show below

```
[{'Transaction_Date': '23/02/22', 'Particulars': 'UPI-RAJESHKUMAR KANOJIA-O112254823B@MAIR', 'Cheque Number': '205482165529', 'ValueDate': '23/02/22', 'Debit': '189', 'Credit': nan, 'Balance': 1939.24, 'IsTransactionStart': True, 'TransactionId': 1}, 
{'Transaction_Date': nan, 'Particulars': 'TEL-AIRP0000001-205482165529-PAYMENT MAD', 'Cheque Number': nan, 'ValueDate': nan, 'Debit': nan, 'Credit': nan, 'Balance': nan, 'IsTransactionStart': False, 'TransactionId': 1}, 
{'Transaction_Date': nan, 'Particulars': 'E TO ME', 'Cheque Number': nan, 'ValueDate': nan, 'Debit': nan, 'Credit': nan, 'Balance': nan, 'IsTransactionStart': False, 'TransactionId': 1}, 
{'Transaction_Date': '24/02/22', 'Particulars': 'UPI-ADD MONEY TO WALLET-ADD-MONEY@PAYTM-', 'Cheque Number': '205599473326', 'ValueDate': '24/02/22', 'Debit': '602', 'Credit': nan, 'Balance': 1337.24, 'IsTransactionStart': True, 'TransactionId': 2}, 
{'Transaction_Date': nan, 'Particulars': 'PYTM0123456-205599473326-NA', 'Cheque Number': nan, 'ValueDate': nan, 'Debit': nan, 'Credit': nan, 'Balance': nan, 'IsTransactionStart': False, 'TransactionId': 2}, 
{'Transaction_Date': '24/02/22', 'Particulars': '.ACH DEBIT RETURN CHARGES 020222 020222-', 'Cheque Number': 'MIR2205429451991', 'ValueDate': '24/02/22', 'Debit': '531', 'Credit': nan, 'Balance': 806.24, 'IsTransactionStart': True, 'TransactionId': 3}, 
{'Transaction_Date': nan, 'Particulars': 'MIR2205429451991', 'Cheque Number': nan, 'ValueDate': nan, 'Debit': nan, 'Credit': nan, 'Balance': nan, 'IsTransactionStart': False, 'TransactionId': 3}]
```

- Is there a way to combine list of dictionary with same `TransactionId` and make a new list as in the expected output.
- Expected Output

```
[{'Transaction_Date': '23/02/22', 'Particulars': 'UPI-RAJESHKUMAR KANOJIA-O112254823B@MAIR TEL-AIRP0000001-205482165529-PAYMENT MAD E TO ME', 'Cheque Number': '205482165529', 'ValueDate': '23/02/22', 'Debit': '189', 'Credit': nan, 'Balance': 1939.24, 'IsTransactionStart': True, 'TransactionId': 1}, 
{'Transaction_Date': '24/02/22', 'Particulars': 'UPI-ADD MONEY TO WALLET-ADD-MONEY@PAYTM-PYTM0123456-205599473326-NA', 'Cheque Number': '205599473326', 'ValueDate': '24/02/22', 'Debit': '602', 'Credit': nan, 'Balance': 1337.24, 'IsTransactionStart': True, 'TransactionId': 2}, 
{'Transaction_Date': '24/02/22', 'Particulars': '.ACH DEBIT RETURN CHARGES 020222 020222-MIR2205429451991', 'Cheque Number': 'MIR2205429451991', 'ValueDate': '24/02/22', 'Debit': '531', 'Credit': nan, 'Balance': 806.24, 'IsTransactionStart': True, 'TransactionId': 3},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pandas` for this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [{'Transaction_Date': '23/02/22', 'Particulars': 'UPI-RAJESHKUMAR KANOJIA-O112254823B@MAIR', 'Cheque Number': '205482165529', 'ValueDate': '23/02/22', 'Debit': '189', 'Credit': np.nan, 'Balance': 1939.24, 'IsTransactionStart': True, 'TransactionId': 1}, 
{'Transaction_Date': np.nan, 'Particulars': 'TEL-AIRP0000001-205482165529-PAYMENT MAD', 'Cheque Number': np.nan, 'ValueDate': np.nan, 'Debit': np.nan, 'Credit': np.nan, 'Balance': np.nan, 'IsTransactionStart': False, 'TransactionId': 1}, 
{'Transaction_Date': np.nan, 'Particulars': 'E TO ME', 'Cheque Number': np.nan, 'ValueDate': np.nan, 'Debit': np.nan, 'Credit': np.nan, 'Balance': np.nan, 'IsTransactionStart': False, 'TransactionId': 1}, 
{'Transaction_Date': '24/02/22', 'Particulars': 'UPI-ADD MONEY TO WALLET-ADD-MONEY@PAYTM-', 'Cheque Number': '205599473326', 'ValueDate': '24/02/22', 'Debit': '602', 'Credit': np.nan, 'Balance': 1337.24, 'IsTransactionStart': True, 'TransactionId': 2}, 
{'Transaction_Date': np.nan, 'Particulars': 'PYTM0123456-205599473326-NA', 'Cheque Number': np.nan, 'ValueDate': np.nan, 'Debit': np.nan, 'Credit': np.nan, 'Balance': np.nan, 'IsTransactionStart': False, 'TransactionId': 2}, 
{'Transaction_Date': '24/02/22', 'Particulars': '.ACH DEBIT RETURN CHARGES 020222 020222-', 'Cheque Number': 'MIR2205429451991', 'ValueDate': '24/02/22', 'Debit': '531', 'Credit': np.nan, 'Balance': 806.24, 'IsTransactionStart': True, 'TransactionId': 3}, 
{'Transaction_Date': np.nan, 'Particulars': 'MIR2205429451991', 'Cheque Number': np.nan, 'ValueDate': np.nan, 'Debit': np.nan, 'Credit': np.nan, 'Balance': np.nan, 'IsTransactionStart': False, 'TransactionId': 3}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
# groupby TransactionID, keep all first column items, except for Particulars - join that one
df = df.groupby('TransactionId', as_index=False).agg({'Transaction_Date': 'first', 'Particulars': '-'.join, 'Cheque Number':'first', 'ValueDate':'first', 'Debit':'first', 'Credit':'first', 'Balance':'first', 'IsTransactionStart':'first', 'TransactionId':'first'})
```

Ouput:

|  | Transaction_Date | Particulars | Cheque Number | ValueDate | Debit | Credit | Balance | IsTransactionStart | TransactionId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 23/02/22 | UPI-RAJESHKUMAR KANOJIA-O112254823B@MAIR-TEL-AIRP0000001-205482165529-PAYMENT MAD-E TO ME | 205482165529 | 23/02/22 | 189 | nan | 1939.24 | True | 1 |
| 1 | 24/02/22 | UPI-ADD MONEY TO WALLET-ADD-MONEY@PAYTM--PYTM0123456-205599473326-NA | 205599473326 | 24/02/22 | 602 | nan | 1337.24 | True | 2 |
| 2 | 24/02/22 | .ACH DEBIT RETURN CHARGES 020222 020222--MIR2205429451991 | MIR2205429451991 | 24/02/22 | 531 | nan | 806.24 | True | 3 |

Convert back to dict:

```
df.to_dict(orient='records')
```

Comment: if i don't know the name of the columns always, can i make it dynamic? And also if there are other overflowing columns, how that can be handled here as for now we are performing join only on a single column.

Comment: @donny try this: `df = df.groupby('TransactionId').agg(lambda x: '-'.join(map(str, filter(pd.notnull,x))))`